# Hololens - Release version not deploying

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, hololens

We've successfully been deploying an app to hololens for the last week. As of 10PM last night, we ceased to be able to deploy the app as a release version for testing. We think it may have to do with the hololens connecting to a service to verify something. Anyone else have a similar issue?

Other native apps work, edge connects to websites.

Windows App Store is not loading.

Answer (score -1):

We got a similar problem. In Debug-Mode everything seems to be fine, but when I change the build settings in Visual Studio to Release the App crashes directly after starting up.

The error message in the console:

```
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): 
"c:\data\Programs\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1_1.1.25129.1_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\entrypoint\HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" geladen. Symbole wurden geladen.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\System.Runtime.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "c:\data\Programs\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1_1.1.25129.1_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\mscorlib.ni.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd" geladen. Das Modul wurde ohne Symbole erstellt.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\UnityPlayer.winmd" geladen. Das Modul wurde ohne Symbole erstellt.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\WinRTBridge.winmd" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\BridgeInterface.winmd" geladen. Das Modul wurde ohne Symbole erstellt.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\System.Collections.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\UnityEngine.dll" geladen. Symbole wurden geladen.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\Assembly-CSharp.dll" geladen. Symbole wurden geladen.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\System.Threading.Tasks.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\UnityEngine.UI.dll" geladen. Symbole wurden geladen.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\System.IO.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\WinRTLegacy.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\Vuforia.UnityExtensions.dll" geladen. Symbole wurden geladen.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\UnityEngine.Networking.dll" geladen. Symbole wurden geladen.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\System.ObjectModel.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\UnityEngine.HoloLens.dll" geladen. Symbole wurden geladen.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\nunit.framework.dll" geladen. Symbole wurden geladen.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\System.Reflection.dll" geladen. Das Modul wurde ohne Symbole erstellt.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\System.Globalization.dll" geladen. Das Modul wurde ohne Symbole erstellt.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\System.Net.Primitives.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\System.Private.Networking.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll" geladen. Das Modul wurde ohne Symbole erstellt.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\System.Xml.XDocument.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\System.Private.Uri.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\System.Text.Encoding.dll" geladen. Das Modul wurde ohne Symbole erstellt.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\UnityEngine.VR.dll" geladen. Symbole wurden geladen.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\System.Threading.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
Loading native plugins
```

Loading VuforiaWrapper.dll

Loading MicStreamSelector.dll

Loading SharingClient.dll

Loading Vuforia.dll

Loading SpatialUnderstanding.dll

Loading PlaneFinding.dll

Loading AudioPluginMsHRTF.dll

Module information:
 Built with Compiler Ver '190023918'
 Built from '5.6/release' branch
 Version is '5.6.1f1 (2860b30f0b54)'
 Release build
 Application type 'D3D11'
 Used 'UWP'

OS 'Windows 10 (10.0.14393)'

PlayerConnection initialized from C:/Data/Users/DefaultAccount/AppData/Local/DevelopmentFiles/HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri/Data (debug = 0)

PlayerConnection initialized network socket : 0.0.0.0 55239

Multi-casting "[IP] 192.168.188.26 [Port] 55239 [Flags] 2 [Guid] 195895822 [EditorId] 4294967295 [Version] 1048832 [Id] MetroPlayerX86(visionme-lens) [Debug] 0" to [225.0.0.222:54997]...

Started listening to [0.0.0.0:55239]

Player data archive not found at `C:/Data/Users/DefaultAccount/AppData/Local/DevelopmentFiles/HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri/Data/data.unity3d`, using local filesystem
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1

Direct3D:

`Version:  Direct3D 11.0 [level 11.1]

Renderer: HoloLens Graphics (ID=0x22b0)

Vendor:   Intel

VRAM:     604 MB`

Initialize engine version: 5.6.1f1 (2860b30f0b54)

"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\UnityEngineProxy.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\System.Linq.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Release_x86.hinri\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll" geladen. Das Modul wurde ohne Symbole erstellt.
OnLevelWasLoaded was found on VuforiaAbstractBehaviour
This message has been deprecated and will be removed in a later version of Unity.
Add a delegate to SceneManager.sceneLoaded instead to get notifications after scene loading has completed

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Mono/MonoScriptCache.cpp Line: 376)

OnLevelWasLoaded was found on VuforiaBehaviour
This message has been deprecated and will be removed in a later version of Unity.
Add a delegate to SceneManager.sceneLoaded instead to get notifications after scene loading has completed

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Mono/MonoScriptCache.cpp Line: 376)

If your machine has multiple graphics adapters, Unity may have created a WindowContext on the wrong adapter. If you experience a black screen when playing, please restart the Editor.

(Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/VR/VRDevice.cpp Line: 184)

Exception thrown: 'System.UriFormatException' in System.Private.Uri.dll
Das Programm "[4504] HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" wurde mit Code -1073741189 (0xc000027b) beendet.

So the important part should be:

Exception thrown: 'System.UriFormatException' in System.Private.Uri.dll
Das Programm "[4504] HoloToolkit-Unity.exe" wurde mit Code -1073741189 (0xc000027b) beendet.